# Grabbing specific table from Word doc in VB.NET ,

Tags: vb.net, ms-word, office-automation

find first cell text or any other way to identify text in table

```
 For h As Integer = 1 To doc.Tables.Count
            Dim table As Table = doc.Tables(h)
            For i As Integer = 1 To table.Rows.Count

                For j As Integer = 1 To table.Columns.Count
                    If table.Cell(1, 1).Range.Text = "Year" Then
                        Dim cellText As String = table.Cell(i, j).Range.Text.Trim()
                        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Cell({0},{1}): {2}", i, j, cellText)
                    End If
                Next
            Next
        Next
```

How do I identify a table I am looking for by its contents to grab?
This destroys the table

```
Dim doc As Word.Document = wordApp.Documents.Open("C:\temp\table.docx")

        ' Read the content of the document
        Dim content As String = doc.Content.Text
        For h As Integer = 1 To doc.Tables.Count
            Dim table As Table = doc.Tables(h)
            Dim str As String
            str = table.ConvertToText(Separator:=vbTab, NestedTables:=False).Text
            MsgBox(str)
```

Comment: This might get you close... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17795717/parse-table-using-microsoft-office-interop-word-get-only-text-from-first-column

Comment: It is not clear what your needs are, but you could use the `Table.Range.Text` property to get all the table text.  Note that the text of each cell ends with a ChrW(13) and ChrW(7) combination.